# Straightforwardly convert dxf to gcode from command-line?

Tags: cam

I have a CAD-produced dxf file containing the design of a 2d part to be cut using CNC. I'm looking for a software that can do the in-between CAM step of converting that dxf to gcode.

I see something called [`dxf2gcode`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dxf2gcode/), but it does not appear to be included in nixpkgs, at least not yet, and I'm just looking for a reliable solution that I can install on nixos without having to create the whole build process myself. Are there any mainstream CAM softwares that can straightforwardly perform this conversion when called from the linux command line? Open-source is preferred.